# Prohibit .APK transfer to TF card or onto another device

Tags: android, apk, file-transfer

Is there a way to prohibit the transfer of an .APK file on a device to another device?

In essence make the .APK "read only" or something similar...

Comment: If an .APK file is read only, as I would expect is the case by default, it fundamentally means one can copy it from the device. Best thing you can do, AFAIK, is to prevent installing on SDcard. Which, once again, is the default as far as I know.

Comment: If you moved a purchased apk to an sdcard and just reinstalled to different device it would not work because of signing, but it's easy to get around if you know how to. So the short answer is not really.

Comment: ok thnx..right. Right using APKInstaller I can export the APK, put in on my PC, then transfer that .apk back to another device..is there a way to disable this export to .apk feature from apps like APKInstaller?